# Wired Serialize result when I dump a struct into file and load it back to memory?

Tags: c++, serialization, visual-c++

I have a unfixed length data stream from website, i want to store it into my self-designed struct, then dump it into file with binary format(for best performance consideration).

because the length is unfixed, i need to use two variable to record the length, in order to know how to load it back.

here is my design for this struct:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sys/time.h>

#pragma pack(8)
struct DepthUpdate {
 typedef double PriceType;
 typedef double VolumeType;
 public:
  timeval t_, ex_t_;
  char ticker_[20];
  size_t data_type_;
  size_t exchange_;
  size_t type_;
  const size_t bid_length_, ask_length_;
  PriceType *bp_, *ap_;
  VolumeType *bv_, *av_;

  DepthUpdate(size_t bid_len, size_t ask_len) : bid_length_(bid_len), ask_length_(ask_len) {
    bp_ = new PriceType[bid_length_];  ap_ = new PriceType[ask_length_];
    bv_ = new VolumeType[bid_length_]; av_ = new VolumeType[ask_length_];
  }

  static void Dump(std::fstream * f, const DepthUpdate* du) {
    f->write((char*)du, calsize(0, 0));
    f->write((char*)du->bp_, sizeof(PriceType)  * du->bid_length_);
    f->write((char*)du->ap_, sizeof(PriceType)  * du->ask_length_);
    f->write((char*)du->bv_, sizeof(VolumeType) * du->bid_length_);
    f->write((char*)du->av_, sizeof(VolumeType) * du->ask_length_);
  }

  static size_t calsize(size_t bid_len, size_t ask_len) {
    return sizeof(DepthUpdate) - sizeof(PriceType*) * 2 - sizeof(VolumeType*) * 2 + (bid_len + ask_len) * sizeof(PriceType) + (bid_len + ask_len) * sizeof(VolumeType);
  }

  
  size_t calsize() const { return calsize(bid_length_, ask_length_); }

  static const DepthUpdate* Load(void * ptr) {
    DepthUpdate* du = (DepthUpdate*)ptr;
    du->bp_ = (PriceType*)((char*)ptr + calsize(0, 0));
    du->ap_ = du->bp_ + du->bid_length_;
    du->bv_ = (VolumeType*)(du->ap_ + du->ask_length_);
    du->av_ = du->bv_ + du->bid_length_;
    return du;
  }

  void Show(FILE * stream, size_t len = 0) const { 
    size_t l = (bid_length_ < ask_length_) ? bid_length_ : ask_length_;
    if (len > l) { printf("Show length exceed %zu (%zu, %zu)\n", len, bid_length_, ask_length_); exit(1); } 
    if (len == 0) len = l;
    fprintf(stream, "%ld %ld %ld %ld | %zu %zu | %zu %zu | %s %zu", t_.tv_sec, t_.tv_usec, ex_t_.tv_sec, ex_t_.tv_usec, data_type_, type_, bid_length_, ask_length_, ticker_, exchange_);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) fprintf(stream, " | %lf %lf %lf x %lf", bp_[i], ap_[i], bv_[i], av_[i]);
    fprintf(stream, "\n");
  }


#pragma pack()
```

the important part is `Dump` and `Load`.

For `Dump`, i just copy the data part into file.

For `Load`, i found the data start address, assign it to `bp_, ap_, bv_, av_`;

I think this is good, the align problem i think i also avoid, because i set the `memory alignment` as 8 byte.

the test code is here:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include "./depth_update.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
  // part 1: dump DepthUpdate in to file
  {
    DepthUpdate du(16, 16);
    gettimeofday(&du.t_, NULL);
    gettimeofday(&du.ex_t_, NULL);
    snprintf(du.ticker_, sizeof(du.ticker_), "asd");
    du.exchange_ = 1;
    du.type_ = 1;
    du.data_type_ = 1;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < du.bid_length_; ++i) {
      du.ap_[i] = i; du.bp_[i] = i;
      du.av_[i] = 1; du.bv_[i] = 1;
    }   
    DepthUpdate du2(13, 13);
    gettimeofday(&du2.t_, NULL);
    gettimeofday(&du2.ex_t_, NULL);
    snprintf(du2.ticker_, sizeof(du2.ticker_), "asd");
    du2.exchange_ = 1;
    du2.type_ = 1;
    du2.data_type_ = 1;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < du2.bid_length_; ++i) {
      du2.ap_[i] = i + 100; du2.bp_[i] = i + 100;
      du2.av_[i] = 1; du2.bv_[i] = 1;
    }   
    std::fstream f;
    f.open("a.bin", std::ios::out);
    if (!f.is_open()) { printf("failed to open file\n"); exit(1); }
    du.Show(stdout);
    du2.Show(stdout);
    DepthUpdate::Dump(&f, &du);
    DepthUpdate::Dump(&f, &du2);
    f.close();

  }

  // part 2: load it back from file
  {
    printf("=====================================================================\n");
    std::fstream f;
    f.open("a.bin", std::ios::in);
    struct stat sb;
    if (lstat("a.bin", &sb) == -1) { printf("stat Failed\n"); exit(1); }
    size_t filesize = sb.st_size;
    char buff[filesize];  // enough space
    f.read(buff, sizeof(buff));
    size_t size = 0;
    char * ptr = buff;
    while (size < filesize) {
      const DepthUpdate * p = DepthUpdate::Load(ptr);
      p->Show(stdout);
      ptr += p->calsize();
      size += p->calsize();
    }
  }
}
```

the output result is very wired, please see this:

```
1667532850 378649 1667532850 378649 | 1 1 | 6 6 | asd 1 | 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 x 1.000000 | 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 x 1.000000 | 2.000000 2.000000 1.000000 x 1.000000 | 3.000000 3.000000 1.000000 x 1.000000 | 4.000000 4.000000 1.000000 x 1.000000 | 5.000000 5.000000 1.000000 x 1.000000
1667532850 378653 1667532850 378653 | 1 1 | 7 7 | asd 1 | 100.000000 100.000000 1.000000 x 1.000000 | 101.000000 101.000000 1.000000 x 1.000000 | 102.000000 102.000000 1.000000 x 1.000000 | 103.000000 103.000000 1.000000 x 1.000000 | 104.000000 104.000000 1.000000 x 1.000000 | 105.000000 105.000000 1.000000 x 1.000000 | 106.000000 106.000000 1.000000 x 1.000000
=====================================================================
1667532850 378649 1667532850 378649 | 1 1 | 6 6 | asd 1 | 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 x 1.000000 | 0.000000 1.000000 1.000000 x 1.000000 | 0.000000 2.000000 1.000000 x 1.000000 | 0.000000 3.000000 1.000000 x 1.000000 | 4.000000 4.000000 1.000000 x 1.000000 | 5.000000 5.000000 1.000000 x 1.000000
1667532850 378653 1667532850 378653 | 1 1 | 7 7 | asd 1 | 0.000000 100.000000 1.000000 x 1.000000 | 0.000000 101.000000 1.000000 x 1.000000 | 0.000000 102.000000 1.000000 x 1.000000 | 0.000000 103.000000 1.000000 x 1.000000 | 104.000000 104.000000 1.000000 x 1.000000 | 105.000000 105.000000 1.000000 x 1.000000 | 106.000000 106.000000 1.000000 x 1.000000
```

As Above, the wired part is:

the load part, `bp_` always lost foremost 4 elements (as 0, which is should not be).

the left part is correct.

but, the other part is based on `bp_`'s pointer, if `bp_` is not correct, they should be all wrong.

could you help on this?

Comment: Do not save the pointer, you should save the content and create a new buffer to hold the content.

Comment: @LouisGo For ```Dump``` function, i think i have used deep copy already.

Comment: 1. you didn't consider the alignment issue. Try to print all the address of the struct and compare with the `calcsize(_1 , _2)`. Better to print show struct and append the buffer instead of directly substract 4 pointers... 2. Serious memory leak. 3. In `Load`,  you should copy the data from char buff[filesize] instead of using it directly, unless you'd like to keep it in the scope;